# Only todays Date id should display in the list in django

Tags: python, django-models, django-templates, django-views

There are different date files stored in the database,while listing only todays date file should display.As i am new to django,plz guide me

views.py

```
def select_date(request):
    pdf = Client_files.objects.all()
    client = Client.objects.all()
    process = Client_Process.objects.all()
    # obj1 = Client_files.objects.filter.all(date__year='2019', date__month='08' , date__day='20')

    return render(request,'select_date.html', {'pdf':pdf,'client':client,'process':process})
```

models.py

```
class Client_files(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    client_process = models.ForeignKey(Client_Process, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    File_Name = models.FileField()
    Pages = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Status = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    class Meta:
        db_table : 'client_files'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can filter with the [**`__date`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date):

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

def select_date(request):
    client = Client.objects.all()
    process = Client_Process.objects.all()
    pdf = Client_files.objects.filter.all(Date__date=now().date())

    return render(request,'select_date.html', {'pdf':pdf,'client':client,'process':process})
```

> **Note**: usually the names of Django models are *singular* and written in `CamelCase`, so `ClientProcess` instead of <s>`Client_Process`</s>, and `ClientFile` instead of <s>`Client_files`</s>. The names of fields are written in `lowercase_with_underscores`, so `date` instead of <s>`Date`</s>, and `file_name` instead of <s>`File_Name`</s>.
>
> **Note**: you made a small typo in the `db_table`, it should be `db_table = 'client_files'`, not <s>`db_table : 'client_files'`</s>.